# How to avoid cross join while trying to use an inner join in the below query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to join 3 tables to get the data into the 4th table. The first 2 table joins are working as expected. But when joining the 3rd table, cross joining is taking place in the result set. Below is the code. I have also attached the screenshot of the target table(which is the last one) and each colored column represents the corresponding column from the src tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
    (SELECT
         os.ServiceId AS ServiceId,
         m.MovieId AS MovieId,
         op.user_id AS UserId,
         op.price AS Price,
         op.transaction_id AS TransactionId,
         op.transaction_date AS TransactionDate,
         GETUTCDATE() AS CreatedDate,
         GETUTCDATE() AS ModifiedDate,
         op.source_filename AS SrcFileName
     FROM
         stg.online_purchase op
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.tOnlineService os ON op.online_service_code = os.ServiceCode
                               AND op.online_service_name = os.ServiceName
     INNER JOIN
         dbo.tmovies m ON op.movie_id = m.MovieIdNK)
```

[image]

There are a 1000 records in `stg.online_purchase` table and when I join it with the `tMovies` table, I am getting the required 1000 records in the target. But when I join `tOnline_Service` table, the cross joining happens.

The `tOnline_Service` is created from the `stg.online_purchase` table and it also has 1000 records.

I am not sure how to avoid the cross joining since `ServiceId` and `ServiceName` are the only columns which I can take to join.

[image]

[image]

Sample data:

`stg.online_purchase`:

```
online_service_name online_service_code movie_id    user_id price   transaction_id  transaction_date    source_filename pipelineId
Disney Plus CCC 420245  9698590 6.72    04b3d119-e15d-4879-b1dc-a2dff0bc26a9    2017-11-13 01:10:29 04b3d119e15d4879b1dca2dff0bc26a9.json   e96deeb6-fd5b-49a6-80c9-dc84936eaec1
HBO AAA 411717  8304573 4.69    01f8047e-a972-44f0-b459-046e8c4a9a12    2017-11-06 11:38:51 01f8047ea97244f0b459046e8c4a9a12.json   e96deeb6-fd5b-49a6-80c9-dc84936eaec1
Disney Plus CCC 419522  9834543 6.92    041072b6-2952-4bea-a07d-f7217e5a2a51    2017-03-13 20:38:09 041072b629524beaa07df7217e5a2a51.json   e96deeb6-fd5b-49a6-80c9-dc84936eaec1
```

`tOnline_Service`:

```
ServiceId   ServiceCode ServiceName CreatedDate ModifiedDate
2001    CCC Disney Plus 2024-01-07 12:51:28.273 2024-01-07 12:51:28.273
2002    AAA HBO 2024-01-07 12:51:28.273 2024-01-07 12:51:28.273
2003    CCC Disney Plus 2024-01-07 12:51:28.273 2024-01-07 12:51:28.273
```

`tMovies`:

```
MovieId MovieIdNK   Budget  HomepagePath    Title   OriginalTitle   ReleaseDate Revenue Runtime MovieStatusId   AvgVote CreatedDate ModifiedDate    SrcFileName
49519   100032  0   NULL    The Great Los Angeles Earthquake    The Great Los Angeles Earthquake    1990-11-11  0   180 40  6.8 2023-12-11 15:37:49.723 2023-12-11 15:37:49.723 movies_metadata_20231211152003.csv
49520   100063  0   NULL    Blackout    Blackout    1978-08-25  0   92  40  5.0 2023-12-11 15:37:49.723 2023-12-11 15:37:49.723 movies_metadata_20231211152003.csv
49521   100152  2000000 NULL    Mars    Марс    2004-11-11  0   100 40  5.0 2023-12-11 15:37:49.723 2023-12-11 15:37:49.723 movies_metadata_20231211152003.csv
```

Comment: Can you describe how is your result wrong and what you would need to have instead?

Comment: I should be able to get 1000 records in total in the target table.

Comment: And it's empty instead?

Comment: I am currently getting 201475 recirds instead

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results as text not images.

Comment: Please show how `tmovies` is defined, I mean the create table statement.

Comment: But tMovies and the stg table are joining perfectly. I am having trouble extracting the ServiceId column from tOnline_Service table. And there are no other columns in tMovies which can be used to join these other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot with data samples shows that your `dbo.tOnlineService` table has duplicate `ServiceCode + ServiceName` pairs. This is where your inflated row count comes from, most likely.

As a side note, why use `ServiceName` in join? Is `ServiceCode` not unique enough?

Comment: It was because i didnt take the distinct values into the table

Answer (score -4):

To avoid cross joining I just needed to take the distinct values of ServiceCode and ServiceName from the stg table and then populate the tOnline_Service table. Basically I needed the ServciceID for each services and according to the rule of Normalization this is what should have been done.

So taking the distinct values into the tOnline_Service table we get:
[image]

and now joining we get 1000 records into the target which was my initial aim. The multiple joins happened because the values in this table were repeating without any other factor joining in.

Comment: You were already advised in the question: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Throwing a `DISTINCT` at a query when you do not understand where the extra rows are coming from is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I just needed to take the distinct values from the table which is actually what i should have done in the beginning.